# Improving MySQL efficiency

Tags: mysql

1. I have a table now containing over 43 million records. To execute `SELECT`, I usually select records with the same field, say `A`. Will it be more efficient to divide the table into several tables by different `A` and save in the database? How much can I gain?
2. I have one table named `entry: {entryid (PK), B}`, containing 6 thousand records, and several other tables with the similar structure `T1: {id(PK), entryid, C, ...}`, containing over millions of records. Do the following two processes have the same efficiency?

   `SELECT id FROM T1, entry WHERE T1.entryid = entry.entryid AND entry.B = XXX`

and

```
SELECT entryid FROM entry WHERE B = XXX
//format a string S as (entryid1, entryid2, ... )
//then run
SELECT id FROM T1 WHERE entryid IN S
```

Comment: Why don't you measure all of this?

Comment: Try use the explain keyword and make sure you index as well as possible if you want quick selects.

Comment: @DerekOrgan What is explain keyword?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html - basically add the word 'EXPLAIN' before your query to see how it uses you indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will get performance improvement. You don't have to do that manually, but use built in [MySQL partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html). How much will you get really depends on your configuration and it would be the best for you to test it. For example, if you have monster server, 43M records is nothing and you will not get that much with partitioning (but you should get improvement anyway).
2. As for this question, I would say that first query will be a lot faster.

But it would be the best to measure your results because it may depend on your hardware coonfiguration, indexes (use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) to check if you have correct indexes), your MySQL settings like query cache size, and engine you are using (MYISAM, InnoDB)...

Answer (score 0):

Use the EXPLAIN Command to check your queries.
dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Here is an explaination
http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained

You need to make sure first and foremost you have the right indexes for a table that size especially for queries that join with other tables.